# jquery: find an input checkbox with a specific label text

Tags: jquery, label

I have a form with a bunch of checkboxes on it with associated labels after them using for=

For a given string (eg "red") how do I get the checkbox that has that label so I can check/uncheck it?

```
<input type="checkbox"  id="chk1" name="chk1" value="0" /><label for="chk1">red</label>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var chckbox_id = $('label[for]').filter(function(){
   return $(this).text() === 'red';
}).attr('for');
$('#'+chckbox_id).prop('checked',!$('#'+chckbox_id).prop('checked')); //this is checbox id
```

Comment: got same idea but yours is more readable (and better first selector) +1

Comment: @A.Wolff thank you bro i like you `htmlFor` pretty awesome :)

Comment: Some of the labels include a &nbsp; before them. In these case the above code finds object[] for some reason.

Comment: @derekcohen than use `return $.trim($(this).text()) === 'red';`

Comment: thanks that works - I didn't realise trim() would remove &nbsp; as well

Answer (score 2):

Try following snippet:

```
var search = "red";
var labelFor = $('label').filter(function(){
    return this.innerHTML === search;
}).get(0).htmlFor;
var $input = $('#'+labelFor);
```

Comment: `.htmlFor?` do you mean to say `.html()`